# Bash Script: Unable to locate package all packages

Tags: bash, apt, cuckoo

[image]

https://github.com/archanchoudhury/Cuckoo-Script/blob/main/Cuckoo-Pre1.sh - bash script

the commands in the above file is running when it is copied and pasted separately but when we run it as bash script it showing error unable to find the package... for all packages

And it will be helpful if anyone can tell how to make the full fledge cuckoo docker file

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 0):

See if below dockerfile will be of any help to you

```
FROM ubuntu
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python-dev \
        python-pip \
        libffi-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        python-virtualenv \
        build-essential \
        git \
        libjpeg-dev \
        zlib1g-dev
    
    RUN git clone https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo.git
    
    RUN cd cuckoo && \
        virtualenv venv && \
        . venv/bin/activate && \
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    
    EXPOSE 8090
    
    CMD ["python", "/cuckoo/cuckoo.py"]
```

Comment: Thanks, cuckoo web and api support will be available?

Comment: i am getting many errors